# Change Bootstrap Popover Message Based on Current Hovered Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have a list, and I want a popover  with a unique message to show when I hover each element. As of right now, the popover is showing properly, but I can't get the html of the popover to be dynamic text.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="step" title="">1</li>
    <li class="step" title="">2</li>
    <li class="step" title="">3</li>
    <li class="step" title="">4</li>
    <li class="step" title="">5</li>
</ul>
```

Coffeescript:

```
$(".step").popover
    html: true
    placement: 'bottom'
    trigger: 'hover'
    content: ->
      html = "This li text is " + $(".step".prev.text)
```

Comment: There needs to be a selector, like an ID separating each step.

Comment: I can't do it based on order? The `popover` element always shows just after whatever element triggers it--so in theory, you could find the element that triggered the event and then make it dynamic based on that.

Comment: @ElijahMurray What exaclty you want to display the text of previous li?

Comment: @PSL I wanted to show the number of the current step. I ultimately wrote a `switch` statement to display a unique message, but for testing purposes this worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JS you can use the `this` inside the `content` property's function which will represent the current `li` in action and you can use that to select the relative content:

```
$(".step").popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: function(){
      return "This li text is " + $(this).text(); //user this as context which will be the current `li`
    }
});
```

Probably with CoffeeScript (Not completely sure about coffee syntax):

```
$(".step").popover
  html: true
  placement: "bottom"
  trigger: "hover"
  content: ->
    "This li text is " + $(this).text()
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8MYr/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use selector option

```
    function updateCodeView() {
     $('#with-selector-code').toggle(usingSelectorOption());
```

**Bootstrap provides a great example here. Be sure to check mark the "use selector option"**

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fScua/

In the view of the example, check the 'use selector option' to see how it works.